# Adobe XD Apple UI resources

Tags: adobe-xd

I want to design a page for Apple using Adobe XD.
When I looked for resources and download them, they were all in .dmg fines.
However, I am using Windows 10. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can open DMGs on Windows with [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) (via context menu) or [DMG Extractor](https://www.dmgextractor.com/) (via UI tool).

[How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/204628/HOW-TO-OPEN-A-DMG-FILE-IN-WINDOWS/) has a usage overview of both.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Windows 10 version from Adobe XD's [official website](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd.html). Addition to that, now you can install various useful plugins of Adobe XD in the application under plugins menu.

As UI components please have a look [official website of xD](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/ui-design-kits.html), [xdguru](https://www.xdguru.com/free-xd-ui-kits/), [blog adobe](https://theblog.adobe.com/five-top-ux-designers-five-ui-kits-adobe-xd-now-available-free/) and [xdresources](https://xdresources.co/). Those are some of the websites where you can find free components for Adobe XD.

When you use search engine, try to search like "Apple UI kit, IOS kits, Material kits etc. "

Hope it will help